# can't install pyside and QT Mac OSX 10.9

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyside

I'm more or less new to python
I'm trying to install pyside and QT on a mac but I can't figure out how to install them.

I downloaded install files "pyside-1.1.0-qt47-py27apple.pkg" from http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide_Binaries_MacOSX and "Qt libraries 4.8.5 for Mac" from http://qt-project.org/downloads.

double click on both files and installed. but it looks like it didn't work.
I can import PySide but nothing else.

in Python Idle when I type

```
import PySide
print PySide.__version__

1.1.0
```

then if I do:

```
import PySide.QtCore
```

I get this error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       import PySide.QtCore ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtCore.so, 2): Library
>   not loaded: QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore   Referenced from:
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtCore.so   Reason: no
>   suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore: mach-o, but
>   wrong architecture

I have python 2.7 and PyCharm. I also have installed setuptools and pip.

I looked around online and I see a lot of people had the same problem. but I couldn't find any answer that worked for me.

I hope anyone can help me out with this.

Comment: I would suggest you to install everything via macports. The problem I found (and maybe it's yours too) by doing package by package is that if pyside has been built against a different qt library from the qt ecosystem you have, things will go wrong soon or later. The advantage of using macports (or other package manager) is that everything is kept uniform.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide#installing-pyside-on-a-mac-os-x-system) worked for me:

```
sudo pyside_postinstall.py -install
```

Note: I'm using PySide 1.2.2, Qt 4.8.6, Mac OS X 10.9.3.

**Edit:** There is no more need to call the post-install script on Linux and MacOS systems since version 1.2.3 (2015-10-12).

Comment: Here's what I got: `sudo: pyside_postinstall.py: command not found` on Mac OS X 10.10.5

Comment: I would advise you to post a new question. Anyway, make sure you installed pyside correctly. pyside_postinstall.py should be located in /usr/local/bin/ if the installation is successful.

Comment: @iled ain't work for me whether use sudo or find it in `/usr/local/bin/` actually pyside_postinatall.py isn't located in there......i still can't install it

Comment: @Sinux please, post a new question, be sure to list all details, including those about what have you tried to do and what error messages are you getting.

Comment: this answer is very confusing

Comment: @Macumbaomuerte Can you please elaborate? What part of the answer do you find confusing? Basically it says to run a script after installation. Please bear in mind that it was posted in 2014. It is outdated for current versions of PySide. I will update the answer with that info.